# How to change the content of a cell keeping formatting with Apache POI

Tags: excel, formatting, apache-poi

I have an Excel document where I need to change the value of a single character inside a cell but keeping the formatting.

Using `setCellValue`, it properly changes the value but completely removes formatting.

Looking at POI documentation, it seems like there is no method to do that out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual with Excel, not super easy but you need to :

- Get the text of the cell
- Keep track of the style on a per-range basis (not on a per-character basis, otherwise italic text look odd)
- Change the text of the cell applying the previous style

```java
// Copy the style of the different ranges
List<XSSFFont> fonts = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> ranges = new ArrayList<>();

String cellText = cell.getStringCellValue();
XSSFRichTextString cellRichText = cell.getRichStringCellValue();

for (int i = 0; i < cellText.length(); i++) {
    XSSFFont font = cellRichText.getFontAtIndex(i);

    fonts.add(font);
    ranges.add(i);

    while (font.equals(cellRichText.getFontAtIndex(i)))
        i++;

    i--;
}

ranges.add(cellText.length());

// Create the new content of the cell
XSSFRichTextString newCellRichText = new XSSFRichTextString(cellText.replace('A', 'B'));

// Apply the style to the new value - In this case, that's
// super easy, there is no need to change the indexes inside
// the `ranges` list as the string has the same size.
for (int i = 0; i < fonts.size(); i++) {
    newCellRichText.applyFont(ranges.get(i), ranges.get(i+1), fonts.get(i));
}

cell.setCellValue(newCellRichText);
```